# Square brackets — not array related?

Tags: c++

I know that hard brackets ('[' and ']') are used to identify an array,
but whilst searching for how to use events I stumbled upon another use for them, and wonder what exactly it means...

The code I saw ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2k0a7d.aspx#Anchor_4)) looks like this:

```
// evh_native.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

[event_source(native)]
class CSource {
public:
   __event void MyEvent(int nValue);
};

[event_receiver(native)]
class CReceiver {
public:
    …
```

So...I wonder what exactly this means and what it is used for? Can someone please explain?

Comment: It is something peculiar to the Windows variant of C++, annotating the behaviour with respect to events.  It is not Standard C++.

Comment: They're [*attributes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwy014e.aspx), a Visual C++-specific language extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the array usage and class `operator[]`, there is another use in C++, the capture list of lambdas, like

```
int a;
auto func= [a](int i){ return i*a; }
```

but the example in your link looks like non-standard (it's referred to as *native* C++, whatever that is). Yet another use are double brackets for attributes, like

```
[[noreturn]] void throw_error(std::string const&message);
```

Answer (score 4):

It could be a few things; to me it looks like your case is the last on my list:

1. To specify an index of an array.
2. To specify the *capture list* in a lambda expression or function.
3. `[]` can be overloaded in a way that it detaches completely from its original intention. Boost spirit does this.
4. A non-standard compiler extension.

1, 2, and 3 can all be implemented in standard C++; 4 cannot.

Comment: Is non-standard still C++?

Comment: @Walter: I'd say no, but I dare say many folk who grew up with the vast array of non-standard compiler extensions to both C and C++ in the 1990s would disagree. Range-based switching is the worst extension I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like C++/CLI code, may be some code from .NET?